# To hide a div section while rendering the vf page as pdf

Tags: visualforce, renderas

I am fairly new to the visualforce development. I created a page which is displaying nicely. While rendering the page with renderas="PDF" i want a particular div tag to hide:

```
<div id="TextCounter">200 characters remaining</div>
```

wondering if we can provide some conditions before rendering as pdf using some kind of boolean variable.

Comment: Hi Neel, welcome to SFSE. Are you rendering your page into PDF only some of the time by using the `getContentAsPDF()` call? If not, how are you doing that conditionally? (Please edit your question to add some context).

Comment: Please try applying this css styling to that div (`style="display: none;"`)

Comment: You can use <apex:outputPanel> tag instead with layout="block" so that it renders as a div. Then you can use the rendered attribute to control when to show it and when to hide.

Answer (score -1):

It worked with the CSS styling suggested by [Nitesh N](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/48406/nithesh-n) in a comment:

```
<div id="TextCounter" style="display: {!IF(printableLead == true, 'none', 'block')};">200 characters remaining</div>
```